# How can i subtract object values having similar keys in an array of object? (not to be confused with removing duplicates)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have an object

```
const testArray = [{key: 'a', value: 5}, {key: 'b', value: 1}, {key: 'a', value: 2}]
```

what I want is

```
newArray = [{key: 'a', value: 3}, {key: 'b', value: 1}]
```

What I tried is

```
testArray.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
    const exists = !!acc && acc.find(item => item.key === cur.key)
    if (!exists){
       acc.push(cur)
    } else {
       // can't figure out what i should do here
    }
    return acc;
}, [])
```

Or Else any other easy solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow community.
I think if key node is key (unique identifier) whose value is a, b ... then you should not  generate array like `[{key: 'a', value: 5}, {key: 'b', value: 1}, {key: 'a', value: 2}]`.
If you have merged array `[{key: 'a', value: 5}, {key: 'b', value: 1}]` and `[{key: 'a', value: 2}]` then unique identifier must be unique.

Please explain question more in details, if possible provide simplest example of problem.

Comment: I receive this format directly from database i.e. its not the result of merging arrays and i need to normalize this in frontEnd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map` where the keys are the `key` property from the objects and values are the entire object.

Now for every object in the `testArray` check if its `key` is present in the `Map`, if it is present, then update only the value, and it is not present set the entire value.

#### Solution Using `Map`

```js
const testArray = [{ key: "a", value: 5 }, { key: "b", value: 1 }, { key: "a", value: 2 }];

const res = Array.from(testArray.reduce(
  (m, o) => (
    m.has(o.key)
      ? m.set(o.key, { ...m.get(o.key), value: m.get(o.key).value - o.value })
      : m.set(o.key, { ...o }),
    m
  ),
  new Map()
).values());

console.log(res)
```

#### Same solution but in a more readable format

```js
const testArray = [{ key: "a", value: 5 }, { key: "b", value: 1 }, { key: "a", value: 2 }];

const res = Array.from(testArray.reduce(
  (m, o) => {
    if (m.has(o.key)) {
      const currVal = m.get(o.key);
      m.set(o.key, {...currVal, value: currVal.value - o.value})
    } else {
      m.set(o.key, {...o})
    }
    return m;
  },
  new Map()
).values());

console.log(res)
```

#### One Liner Using Objects

If the `key` is not present in the object then create an object where the `value` property is double the actual value.

Now for every object, just subtract the current value with the already existing value.

```js
const 
   testArray = [{ key: "a", value: 5 }, { key: "b", value: 1 }, { key: "a", value: 2 }],
   
   res = testArray.reduce((m, {key, value}) => (m[key] ??= ((value) => ({key, value}))(2*value), m[key].value -= value, m), {});


console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Comment: @TilakBasyal Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you use `Array#find`, the result value will keep the reference. So when you change the content it will affect the array `acc`.

```js
const testArray = [{key: 'a', value: 5}, {key: 'b', value: 1}, {key: 'a', value: 2}];

const result = testArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const exists = acc.find(item => item.key === cur.key)
  if (!exists) acc.push(cur);
  else exists.value -= cur.value;
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `Array.prototype.reduce` combine with `Array.prototype.findIndex` to update the result array like this

```js
const testArray = [{key: 'a', value: 5}, {key: 'b', value: 1}, {key: 'a', value: 2}]

let result = testArray.reduce((accumulator, current, index)=>{
  let itemExists = accumulator.findIndex(item => {
    return item.key == current.key;
  });
  
  if(itemExists !== -1){
      current = {...current, value: accumulator[itemExists].value - current.value};
      accumulator[itemExists] = current;
      return accumulator;
  } else {
     return [...accumulator,current];
  }
},[])

console.log(result);
```

The idea is when the `current` item doesn't exists in the result array we just add it to the array otherwhise we update the value of the existing one by updating It value key with the existing one `value` key minus the value key of the `current` item value